# Update file encoding in a Git repo with Azure DevOps REST API

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-repos

There is a Pushes client in Azure DevOps REST API that allows to create pushes with new commits. I followed examples provided [in here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pushes/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) however there isn't one where a file encoding is to be changed. I tried to provide the necessary encoding in a request payload as follows:

```
  "refUpdates": [{ "name": "refs/heads/master", "oldObjectId": "..." }],
    "commits": [{
      "comment": "Comment",
      "changes": [{
        "changeType": 2, // also tried type "4" which stands for "Encoding"
        "item": {
          "path": "...",
          "contentMetadata": { "encoding": 1252 } // UTF-8
        },
        "newContent": { content: "New content", contentType: 0 },
      }]
    }]
```

but it doesn't do anything, "contentMetadata" field seems to be ignored by the Pushes client.

Is there a way to change a file encoding using Azure DevOps REST API?

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduced the same issue. The contentMetadata field got ignored and the file encoding failed to be updated.

You can report this issue to Microsoft development team in the [Developer Community website](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/post.html?space=21). Hope they will look into this issue and provide a fix.